# Woocommerce does not show a sidebar on my shop page?

Tags: woocommerce, sidebar

Even with a woosidebars plugin, my sidebar doesn't show on the shop page. I think it may be due to the free plan theme limitations, however on the pro theme description it doesn't mention an added feature. Could anybody help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must check your shop page template, usually it is placed in the folder /woocommerce of the theme. Sidebar must been there, find it by id.

Also you can to rewrite Woocommerce templates and add the sidebars here: just create the new directory named Woocommerce in your theme and add your customized templates here. In this case, you need to name the template files exactly as they are called in the plugin, you can [see it here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/release/3.2/templates)